# MVC reusing model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I have an MVC Web Application which uses a form to get a postal code from the user, which then queries an external web service and returns a list of addresses to the view.

I had a previous issue whereby my model was static, therefore the data was being displayed to users on other clients, rather than being specific to each user. I have now got it so each individual user can query and get their list of addresses on the view (which isn't visible to anyone else) however, when the user refreshes the page or goes back, the data is lost.

I have some code on the page refresh which checks if the data is there and won't take the user to the start of the form, however on page refresh the model returns to null, hence it will always take them back to the beginning.

Any ideas? I ideally want to be able to use the data multiple times for the current user, but if they refresh and are say 90% through the form, they will lose the whole data. It seems like it should be easy but all of the examples I have tried haven't worked for my particular scenario.

Controller:

```
public class AssistedController : Controller
{
    // GET: Assisted
    AddressList model;


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetAddresses(string postcode)
    {
        model = new AddressList();
        if (postcode == null || postcode == "")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("/Index/");
        }
        //call enviroweb web service
        AddressWeb ew = new AddressWeb();
        //extract address values from the XML returned from web service
        XmlNode xml = ew.GetAddress(", , , , " + postcode);

        foreach (XmlElement addressInfo in xml)
        {
            foreach (XmlElement teset in addressInfo["Addresses"])
            {
                //add each address item found to the list
                model.listone.Add(new AddressResults {
                    FullAddress = teset["fulladdress"].InnerText,
                    Lat = teset["Lat"].InnerText,
                    Lon = teset["Long"].InnerText,
                    addLine1 = teset["addline1"].InnerText,
                    addLine2 = teset["addline2"].InnerText,
                    addLine3 = teset["addline3"].InnerText,
                    addLine4 = teset["addline4"].InnerText,
                    Town = teset["Town"].InnerText,
                    postcode = teset["postcode"].InnerText,
                    Ownership = teset["Ownership"].InnerText,
                    WeekNumber = teset["WeekNumber"].InnerText

                });
            }
        }

        //return the list and model back to the index view
        return View("Index", model);


    }
```

View:

```
<!--Use the model to return the data-->
@model AddressSearch.Models.AddressList
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@if (Model == null)
{

}
  else
{
if (Model.listone.Count != 0)
  {

//this section returns the items as options in the select if the list count is greater than 0.
foreach (var test in Model.listone)
 {
 <option value="@test.FullAddress">@test.FullAddress</option>
                                }



                            }
                        }
```

Model:

```
public class AddressList
{
    public List<AddressResults> listone = new List<AddressResults>();
}
```

Comment: If the user refreshes the page, then they are calling the GET method which returns an empty `AddressList`. You can make a GET to a method which accepts `string postcode` as a parameter rather than making a POST (or just change the `Index()` method to accept `string postcode`)

Comment: Once the user has initially entered their postcode and searched, the webservice stores that data in the 'AddressList' model. Is there a way I can keep AddressList populated rather than keeping the postcode? This would mean having to re-call the web service to obtain the address information if the user refreshed the page.

Comment: The web is stateless - your `AddressList` model is initialized again in each request, so not unless you store the results elsewhere (e.g. `Session`, `MemoryCache` etc) - and you would first check for the results there before calling the web service.

Comment: I've used a session and it has done exactly what it should do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TempData in ASP.NET MVC can be used to store temporary data which can be used in the subsequent request. TempData will be cleared out after the completion of a subsequent request.

```
public class AssistedController : Controller
{
    // GET: Assisted
    AddressList model;


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (TemData.ContainsKey("address"))
        {
            model = TempData["address"] as AddressList;
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetAddresses(string postcode)
    {
        model = new AddressList();
        if (postcode == null || postcode == "")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("/Index/");
        }
        if (TemData.ContainsKey("address"))
        {
            model = TempData["address"] as AddressList;
            return View(model);
        }
        //call enviroweb web service
        AddressWeb ew = new AddressWeb();
        //extract address values from the XML returned from web service
        XmlNode xml = ew.GetAddress(", , , , " + postcode);

        foreach (XmlElement addressInfo in xml)
        {
            foreach (XmlElement teset in addressInfo["Addresses"])
            {
                //add each address item found to the list
                model.listone.Add(new AddressResults
                {
                    FullAddress = teset["fulladdress"].InnerText,
                    Lat = teset["Lat"].InnerText,
                    Lon = teset["Long"].InnerText,
                    addLine1 = teset["addline1"].InnerText,
                    addLine2 = teset["addline2"].InnerText,
                    addLine3 = teset["addline3"].InnerText,
                    addLine4 = teset["addline4"].InnerText,
                    Town = teset["Town"].InnerText,
                    postcode = teset["postcode"].InnerText,
                    Ownership = teset["Ownership"].InnerText,
                    WeekNumber = teset["WeekNumber"].InnerText

                });
            }
        }
        TempData["address"] = model;
        //return the list and model back to the index view
        return View("Index", model);
    }
}
```

Refer [this link](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc) to how to use